# Prooving ( ∃x Fx ∨ ∃x ~Fx) from no premises

Tags: logic, proof

I have a proof problem which I am stuck on.

```
{ } ⊢ ( ∃x Fx ∨ ∃x ~Fx)
```

I already figured it out in order to get a∨b, I will have to do ~a→b or ~b→a. However, I have absolutely no idea how to get to there `~∃x Fx → ∃x ~Fx` or `~∃x ~Fx → ∃x Fx`.

These rule of inference are allowed: http://pastebin.com/4CFaYVzT and http://pastebin.com/V3GsrvUG

Can someone guide me through this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused. This is false if the domain is empty.

Comment: You need to add your quantifier rules to your Pastebin file!

Comment: @PaulRoss - Added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assume the negation of this sentence and easily derive a contradiction from it. By DeMorgan's laws it becomes the conjunction of two negations. Each of these negations is a negated existential sentence which is the equivalent of a universally quantified negation. That is, you have the conjunction of "everything is not F" and "everything is not not F". Separate them via conjunction-elimination and instantiate them and you have a contradiction. It might look like ~Fa and ~~Fa.